# How to access a java.util.prefs.Preferences object defined in another class

Tags: java, class, preferences

I am seeking to understand how to access a `java.util.prefs.Preferences` object that is defined in a different class. Or, for that matter, what are the best practices for using `Preferences`?

I currently have the preferences saved from a Settings dialog, like so:

```java
public class Settings extends JDialog {
    // [...]
    private final Preferences prefs = Preferences.userRoot().node(this.getClass().getName());
    // [...]
}
```

This works great for setting the various preferences, reverting to defaults, etc. However, once those preferences are saved, I'll need to access them from another class, specifically, my main dialog. However, once the `Settings` dialog has been disposed of, there seems to be no way to access its prefs. And I cannot use `this.getClass().getName()` if I make `prefs` static.

I cannot seem to find any information on how to do this properly and need guidance. What do I need to do? I wouldn't mind putting `prefs` into its own class, but I will still run into the static problem and referencing it from another class.

Comment: You can use the same code. Just replace `this.getClass()` with [Class.forName](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#forName(java.lang.String)) and supply the [fully qualified] name of class `Settings`.

Comment: Thanks for replying, @Abra. So, would I need to change the declaration in `Settings` to `public static final Preferences prefs = Preferences.userRoot().node(Class.forName("info.chrismcgee.sky.artdept.Settings").getName());`? (Then surround it with try/catch, of course.) Because if `.node()` just requires a string, I could just give it the (fully-qualified?) name without going through `Class.forName()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [Preferences](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.prefs/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html) object is obtained via a lookup. It doesn't matter where you are in the code, if you use the same lookup key, you get the same `Preferences` object. The [API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/preferences/overview.html) provides different lookup methods. You just have to select one and be consistent. In my code I use [static] method [userNodeForPackage](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.prefs/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html#userNodeForPackage(java.lang.Class)). The method accepts a single parameter which is a `Class` object. As long as I call method `userNodeForPackage` and pass the same `Class` object, I will get the same `Preferences` object.

One way (but not the only way) to obtain a `Class` object is via [static] method [forName](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#forName(java.lang.String)) in class `java.lang.Class`. However, the way you obtain the `Class` object is irrelevant, just as long as you obtain the correct `Class` object.

Perhaps this article will be helpful:
[The Preferences API](https://blogs.oracle.com/corejavatechtips/the-preferences-api)

Comment: Indeed, that was quite helpful. Good explanation that there are many ways to achieve the same `Preferences` object. I wound up using `private final Preferences prefs = Preferences.userNodeForPackage(this.getClass());` in the `Settings` class and `public final Preferences prefs = Preferences.userNodeForPackage(Settings.class);` in the main dialog's class. Both of those should reference the same object. Thank you so much, @Abra!